# Why is a Custom Preference Center required for Multi-Org Accounts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, subscriber

One of my clients has a Multi-Org account and I am trying to explain why they need a custom Preference Center.

I checked the documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_configuration.htm&type=5 and it's written:

> Custom Profile Centers are required for Multi-Org accounts. Customers
>   can view and edit selected profile attributes and global subscription
>   preferences with a Custom Profile Center.

Only it doesn't explain why that's necessary. Can someone help me with the implications of using the Standard Preference Center? Does it mean that if someone unsubscribes from one business unit it will also unsubscribe from all the others? If that's the case, would it work to use Publication Lists (e.g. BU1, BU2, etc)?

Or it just simply doesn't work at all?

Answer (score 2):

Your standard profile center(s) will work OK in M-O tenant. You cannot have different profile attributes in separate BU's as there's a master Subscriber list in the TOP BU - this is the main reason I believe... You have to store those in a Data Extension for instance (custom PC)

Custom PC can be customized and have any look you want... AMPScript combined with SSJS will help you to achieve what you need and expand your custom PC's functionalities - even modify SFDC objects if you like.